Updates have broken my USB DAC
Unexpected Xubuntu updates have broken my USB DAC for music playing. The DAC works with one computer having (uname -r) kernel 6.5.0-28_generic. I have two others with kernel 6.5.0-35 which report in dmesg:
perhaps the cable is broken, cannot enumerate

All 3 computers have (lsb_release -a) Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic, but that is not true because they have been updated at different times.

Please file a bug report for the regression. AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker, and discussion here will not be seen by the kernel engineers.

Meanwhile, you can boot with an older kernel https://askubuntu.com/a/82145/124466. Also, try Ubuntu 24.04 using a live USB, and check whether the bug is fixed there. If it is fixed, fresh install 24.04
